# executing a block of code repeatedly without a timeout. windows service

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a simple windows service written, here is its skeleton:

```
internal class ServiceModel {
    private Thread workerThread;
    private AutoResetEvent finishedEvent;
    private Int32 timeout = 60000*15;

    public void Start() {
        this.workerThread = new Thread(this.Process);
        this.finishedEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        this.workerThread.Start();
    }

    public void Stop() {
        this.finishedEvent.Set();
        this.workerThread.Join(30000);
    }

    public void Process() {
        while(!this.finishedEvent.WaitOne(timeout)) {
            // run things here
        }
    }
}
```

**the first thing**

The first thing that I can't understand is that service waits one timeout before running. Would rewriting the `new AutoResetEvent(false);` to `new AutoResetEvent(true);` cause a service to start without waiting?

**the second thing**

Due to some internal reasons (requesting data from external server/service, exception handling) sometimes it is not enough to wait that fixed 15..30-minutes timeout.

How do I rewrite it to work without a fixed timeout?
Do I need to remove that `AutoResetEvent` instance at all and run `Process` body inside an infinite loop?

```
public void Process() {
    while(true) {
        // run things here
    }
}
```

**edit. try-catch/lock**

In `Process` method there is a global `try-catch` block:

```
public void Process() {
    do {
        try {
            // processing goes here
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            Logger.Log.Warn(ex); // or Log.Fatal(ex)...
        }
    }
    while(true);
}
```

if I use a *synchronization object* where do I put the `lock` statement so that I'm able to call `break` when `isStopped` is true?

Comment: Although there are better ways to write this requirement. But for a quick fix, why your loop is not a do..while loop to resolve your first thing?

Comment: Does the external service signal you anything when it is ready again?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I'm simply polling it.

Comment: It may be slow. Your look timeout is a lot larger than the timeout in thread.join which means that you may get a timeout in the later if the first is simply slow.

Comment: What do you want instead of a timeout? you still have to wait those 15-30 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to deal with low-level thread and synchronization primitives API. Consider using [Task Parallel Library (TPL)](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/task-parallel-library/info). It's easy to implement `OnStop` using [TPL cancellation framework](http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/C/F/BCFD4868-1354-45E3-B71B-B851CD78733D/UsingCancellationinNET4.pdf):

```
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WindowsService1
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        CancellationTokenSource _mainCts;
        Task _mainTask;

        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        async Task MainTaskAsync(CancellationToken token)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                // ... 
                await DoPollingAsync(token);
                // ... 
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            _mainCts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            _mainTask = MainTaskAsync(_mainCts.Token);
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            _mainCts.Cancel();
            try
            {
                _mainTask.Wait();
            }
            catch
            {
                if (!_mainTask.IsCanceled)
                    throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Inside `MainTaskAsync` you can use `Task.Run` for any CPU-bound work items.

Comment: I can do this only by uisng reactive extensions. But I think it's worth a try))

Comment: @lexeme, if you have continuous asynchronous stream(s) of data to process, then yes, it makes sense to use Rx. In either case, Rx, Dataflow or bare TPL are better tools than raw multithreading API.

Answer (score 1):

using Threads you can achieve your requirement using the following code:

```
internal class ServiceModel {
    private Thread workerThread;
    private object syncLock = new object();
    private bool stop = false;
    public void Start() {
        this.workerThread = new Thread(this.Process);
        this.workerThread.Start();
    }

    public void Stop() {
            lock(syncLock) stop = true;
            this.workerThread.Join(30000);
    }

    public void Process() {
        while(true){
           //your stuff here.
          lock(syncLock)
          {
             if(stop)
                 break;
          }
          Thread.Sleep(30000); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do I need a synchronization object?

Comment: @lexeme You need it for exclusive read or write. Just think what will happen when you stop = true instruction is half way executed by CPU but not put back to be read by your workerThread, your worker thread will go one more cycle to fech data and sleep for 30 seconds. In between your main thread will time out in Join(...) due to this dirty read resulting in unknown behaviour.

Comment: Why do the thread need to sleep for a 30 seconds at the end of computations?

Comment: @lexeme This was your requirement. You can make it anything. Just make sure the Join(...) and Sleep(...) time is same.

Comment: And one more question. I have a try catch block inside the while loop. How do I safely call the lock statement, where should I put it?